# Cell value change to be photo after be summed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i'm working with downloaded excel sheet from the internet.

on it i have a cell that make normal sum to three other cells
[image]

Then, the sum value of that cell( on the same cell )changed to a photo based on the result ( the result sum number not showing at all , only the photo ).

[image]

The threshold ( the value each image change to another one , is dynamic and depend on another cells , so if i change any of that cells , the value the image change from one to another also change ) .

i want to modify that calculation , but i can't find where he is making it

i tried to check if there is any hidden formula or taps , but there is nothing

can any one help me to find how he make it ??

Comment: Any hidden columns or sheets? That is how I would do it at least. Put the calculations in a hidden cell then output the image on a visible cell with conditional formatting. Edit I see now you are asking for the formatting and not the calculations. Check conditonal formatting or the cell formatting

Answer (score 0):

i get it , it was based on conditional formatting rule applied to that cell

[image]